# Use JavaScript to find a specific link

Tags: javascript, url, search, ecmascript-6, css-selectors

Could anyone help me with a function for JavaScript which searches the source code and compares all of the links on the site with the specific link I am looking for.

For example: I am executing the JavaScript on `www.youtube.com` and I am looking for one specific YouTube link.

It could look like this (which of course doesn't work):

```
if(document.body.indexOf("http://www.youtube.com/SPECIFICURL")!== -1){
    console.log("Url found");
}else{
  console.log("Url not found");

}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: First off you need to get all the links on the page using document.links then loop through those using the indexOf function.

Comment: You don't want to search source code. You have a DOM at your disposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function find_link_by_href(address)
    links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
      if( links[i].href === address ) {
        console.log("Url found"); 
        return; 
     } 
 }
```

You can call it like this:

```
find_link_by_href("http://www.youtube.com/SPECIFICURL");
```

Comment: DontVoteMeDown, I upvoted yours and @cookie monster answers, they're actually better than mine :)

Answer (score 12):

Try `querySelectorAll()` with CSS3 selectors:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="http://www.youtube.com/SPECIFICURL"]')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shEX5/1/)

This selector says find all links with an href attribute that contains a specific string. Lets break this down a little bit:

- `a` - this is the element type, e.g. "link"
- `href` - this is the element attribute
- `*=` - this essentially means contains. There are different type of equality checks that can be used: starts with, contains word, ends with, etc. The [jQuery selectors documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is quite good.
- `"..."` - everything in quotes after the equal sign is the substring the query is looking for.

Comment: What is a CSS3 selector ? :D
And how do I use it?

Comment: @user3361146 *selector* is that query string that the engine uses to match desired elements. In the case I used, `a` is saying that you want an anchor tag (`<a>`) that haves the `href` attribute (because its given inside `[]`) that *contains* (`*=`) the substring inside the double-quotes. If you're still confused, try reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Comment: @user3361146 I remembered [this jQuery article](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) about selectors that is good too. Works with the same logic.

Comment: Got what I was looking already but still thanks for your time and work!

Comment: @user3361146 nevermind, you're welcome. Just try to learn something from my and from cookie master answers. Will give you an additional knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.some` to see if at least one element in `document.links` has the `href` you're looking for.

```
var has_link = [].some.call(document.links, function(link) {
   return link.href === 'http://www.youtube.com/SPECIFICURL';
});
```

---

You can patch it in old browsers using the patch found at [`MDN Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Got what I was looking already but still thanks for your time and work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.links to get the anchors, then just loop through grabbing the href, like this:

```
    var arr = [], l = document.links;
    for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
      arr.push(l[i].href);
    }

//arr is now an array of all the href attributes from the anchors in the page
```

[See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/E28eh/)

Then loop through the array to check for your specific link.

Comment: Got what I was looking already but still thanks for your time and work!